# Managed VM not running Cloud SQL Proxy

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, google-managed-vm

Launching a Managed VM with a Java application, the following appengine-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <application>thmadmin-ben</application>
    <version>master</version>
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
    <vm>true</vm>
    <manual-scaling>
        <instances>1</instances>
    </manual-scaling>
</appengine-web-app>
```

I don't appear to have a Cloud SQL proxy running on the managed VM. Do I need to add an app.yaml file or define something else in appengine-web.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/java/configuring-your-app-with-appengine-web-xml), you need to specify the instances which you will be connecting to as follows and redeploy your application.

When using appengine-web.xml, the syntax would be:

```
<beta-settings>
  <setting name="cloud_sql_instances" value="<PROJECT-ID>:<REGION-NAME>:<SQL-INSTANCE-NAME>[, ...]" />
</beta-settings>
```

If this setting is not present, the Cloud SQL Proxy won't start.

Comment: OK I have the /cloudsql file present now on a Managed VM, but I can't seem to connect to the cloud sql DB. I've apt-get installed the mysql-client but running mysql -uroot -p -S /cloudsql/XXX:us-east1:YYY results in ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0 - I cant see anything I need to enable on the cloud SQL instance, and it's running as part of the same project - any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, the Cloud SQL Admin API may not be enabled for your project. Try enabling it via https://console.cloud.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=sqladmin

This step is missing from the docs :(

Comment: That did finally work - frustrating it's not documented. In the end I was unwilling to force the framework I was using to use Socket connections as opposed to TCP ones. Is there a way to have the proxy to proxy TCP port 3306 locally through the socket?